# Stuck with database query

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I run this query:

```
select date, sum(orders) as "Total orders" 
from tbl 
where date >=1 and date <= 4 
group by date
```

How can I get the expected output as shown in the screenshot?

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Why does query not show GROUP BY clause? Join to a table that has all Date values. Do the join either before or after aggregating.

Comment: Your query appears incomplete.  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) +  [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left against generate_series():

```
select g.date, 
       sum(tbl.orders) as "Total orders" 
from generate_series(1,4) as g(date)
  left join tbl on tbl.date = g.date 
group by g.date
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH cte as (

SELECT date, orders
FROM dbo.Orders

),

cte2 as (

select top (SELECT MAX(date) FROM cte) ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a.name) 
as date
from sys.all_objects a

) 

SELECT cte2.date, SUM(ISNULL(orders, 0))
FROM cte2 LEFT JOIN cte ON cte2.date = cte.date
GROUP BY cte2.date
```

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your efforts....But this is not giving desired results. I want that 0 to be assigned to total orders for a date which is in the range of where clause and which doesn't have any order